# How to insert pagination in my backbone.js exercise

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm trying to learn backbone.js and in this exercise I have a view that show elements from a collection. This collection fetch data from a backend that export json file like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Jeffrey Way",
            "age": 27
        },
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 50,
            "occupation": "web designer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sally Doe",
            "age": 29,
            "occupation": "graphic designer"
        }
    ],
    "count": 9,  // total users
    "page": 0,   // current page
    "pages": 2   // total page
}
```

I like to insert pagination in this example but I don't know how.
I know that there is a component [Backbone.paginator](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator) that seems cool.
Could you help me to insert Backbone.paginator in my example? 
If you know another way to implement pagination for my purpose could you explain to me?

This is my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>User List</title>

  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" value="" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      color: #333333;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .pagination {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-user">
  user: <%= name %>, <%= age %>, <%= occupation %> 
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main" class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="header" class="span6">
          <!--
          <h1>Advertisers</h1>
          <p>La ricerca ha prodotto {{ count }} risultati.</p>
          -->
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="input-append" style="text-align:right; margin-top:18px;">
            <input id="contact-to-search" class="span5" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
            <button id="src-btn" class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="pagination" class="pagination">
      <!--
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
      -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my **main.js**

```
// Models
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        "name" : "No Name",
        "age" : "No Age",
        "occupation" : "No occupation"
    }
});



//Collections
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:User,
    url:"json2.json",
    parse: function(response){
       return response.users;
    }
});



// Views
var UserCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'ul',

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function () {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (user) {
            $(this.el).append(new UserView({model:user}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:"li",

    template:_.template($('#tpl-user').html()),

    render:function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});



// Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"list"
    },

    list:function () {
        this.user_collection = new UserCollection();
        this.user_collection_view = new UserCollectionView({model:this.user_collection});
        this.user_collection.fetch();
        $('#content').html(this.user_collection_view.el);
    }
});


// Main
var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Thank You so much from Italy!!

Comment: Have a look at this plugin: https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator